# Sending messages between two chrome background scripts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

I have 2 background scripts one is background.js and other one is background.ts when I build everything inside build file it looks something like this:
/build
|-background.js
|-helper
|--background.ts

What I want to achieve is that I want to send chrome message from .js to .ts background - is that communication possible at all?
Both of background are working and everything is great except lack of communication between them.

I have tried to send message from background.js to content script and then to background.ts and it seems that is working but content script is depending on tabs, and I would like to have direct communication channel between background scripts.

Comment: Chrome extension can have only one background script

Comment: Not true: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background-pages#manifest

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant there is always only one background context, even if you put multiple script files there, they are all executed in same context. Same as you can put multiple <script> tags on page and they will be all executed in same context. So you don't need any communications API (like chrome.runtime.sendMessage) to exchange data between scripts. How exactly you exchange data between scripts will depend on your project or/and goal, but it's really more like two building bricks of one background script rather than two separate entities

Comment: Oh thanks for explanation. Well if I receive socket message in backgroun.js with some data, how to access to that data inside other background.ts? I mean if we don't need some communications between them as you said they are in same context - how to access to data from one in another?

Comment: That depend on what exactly you would like to do with it. If you want to run some function from TS file when you get WS message, you could just import than function into JS file and call in WS message handler. If you need to save message somewhere to later be processed by function from TS file when another event happens, you might need to store it in variable in separate file and import it in both scripts.

Comment: But I'd really recommend to have one 'main' background script and helper files with functions which you import, rather than trying to have two separate files and then trying to integrate them with each other. This will make code easier to understand and split into separate functions/files once main script becomes too big to keep everything in one file

Comment: Hmm, Im not sure that I understand, but you are right regarding my example. I want to activate some function in back.ts when I get that socket msg in back.js but as I said I still don't really understand how to do that as to me those 2 look like 2 different projects even though they work as one.
Regarding one background script I know that this is maybe not the best practice but because of complexity and too many differences between scripts I had to do it like this. I would really appreciate if you know for some example where I can see how 2 back scripts communicate.

Comment: You can add `export` keyword to function definition (e.g. `export const funcName = () => {...}` or `export function funcName() {...}`) and then just import function in background.js like this: `import {funcName} from './path/to/background.ts'`

Comment: What? Thats really a thing? I will definitely try it thank you a lot!

Comment: If you want, you can leave a comment where you explain this, so I can accept is as a solution :)

Comment: That would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always only one background context, even if you put multiple script files there, they are all executed in same context. Same as you can put multiple  tags on page and they will be all executed in same context. So you don't need any communications API (like chrome.runtime.sendMessage) to exchange data between scripts. How exactly you exchange data between scripts will depend on your project or/and goal, but it's really more like two building bricks of one background script rather than two separate entities

If you want to run some function from background.ts file when you get WS message, you could just import than function into background.js file and call in WS message handler.

To do this you'll need to add `export` keyword to function definition in background.ts:

```js
export const funcName = () => {...}
// Or
export function funcName() {...}
```

And then import it in background.js and use as normal function:

```js
import {funcName} from './path/to/background.ts'
```